# How to type special key using Sikuli Java Standalone jar?

Tags: java, sikuli

In [Sikuli X](http://www.sikuli.org) I can use something like

```
type("x", KEY_CTRL)
```

How can I do the same in [Sikuli API](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the key codes in [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html):

```
DesktopKeyboard keyboard = new DesktopKeyboard();
keyboard.keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
keyboard.type("x");
keyboard.keyUp(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: That work! By the way how about Key and KeyModifire class in Sikuli API ?

Comment: `Key` is a set of constants that use private Unicode chars to represent modifier and numpad keys.  You can use them in place of KeyEvent if you like (I see no advantage either way).  `KeyModifier` is used internally in Sikuli's `AWTRobot` but in unreachable code, so it's either future code or defunct code.

Answer (score 1):

I used in my projects this way:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();

screen.click(<your texbox>); // click into textbox to have a cursor there

screen.type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL); // this sends Ctrl+"a" to select all text <- this is what you asked for !
screen.type(Key.BACKSPACE); // this sends Backspace key pressed, i.e. here deletes all selected text
```

Note that I used both KeyModifier and Key. This way it worked.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. None of the Key or KeyModifier events seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
screen.type("x",Key.CTRL)
screen.type("\n");
```